# Subsurface Scattering on a proxy object

Tags: compositing-nodes, subsurface-scattering, proxies

I have an object that has a very fine geometry.
[image: Fine Geometry object]

Now I would like to apply Subsurface Scattering, but since the object is made out of a lot of individual tubes, the Subsurface Scattering is not working as wanted. I assume, that the geometry is the reason for this.
[image: Wrong Subsurface Scattering]

The SS that I would like looks like this. I did this on a simpler geometry without the tubes.
[image: Correct Subsurface Scattering]

Is it possible to sort of tell the shader: "Use SS but with a geometry from another object"
I would like to avoid doing it with the compositor and rendering twice.

Comment: Tubes are open or filled? If you enable Face Orientation overlay -Normals are orientated, correctly (blue)? Since correct SSS appearance is based on object shape you cant get it correct with different (proxy) shape ... and I don't think you can fake it other than composite way.

Comment: Instead of using the SSS from the proxy object on the highpoly object, why not bake the normals from the high poly object to the low and then render the low poly object with its own SSS?